# WooCommerce not applying cupons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After a migration, my WooCommerce can't find the coupons.

I've already checked the **wp_posts** table, and they are there.
I even tried to get then with get_posts() function, and that works, so the coupons are there. They are public, but WooCommerce is not finding then.

Any ideas?

[image: Printscreen of the system page, where there's an alert: "The coupon doesn't exist!" and above the dump of the same coupon post]

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you recently update WooCommerce? If so check to make sure that there is not a prompt asking you to update the database at the top of the screen whilst logged into the dashboard.
2. Go into one of the coupons, assuming everything goes ok try saving it, then see if you can find that specific coupon.
3. Make sure that the coupons conditions allow you to include it at checkout.

From how you've described the problem it sounds like there is something wrong with the meta attached to the coupons rather than the details in wp_posts. Hope this helps.

Koda

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I've discovered that the problem was a change on MySQL charset after migration. The cupons was UPPERCASE on the table, and the WooCommece uses lowercase by default.
So, fixed. :)